# How to trigger enter after changing input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I could change the value of it to something, take 15 for example, and then entering it straight after as you would do manually. I looked up on things like "trigger" but it really confused me.

```
<input class="Paging_Input" data-se="trade-inventory-input-page" type="text">
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate on what the issue is and show us what you've tried.

Comment: @j08691 I mean, an input box where you can input numbers for example. How would you, with javascript, or jquery, change the value of it, and then enter it straight after as you would manually.

Comment: I want to know how to change the input and then enter it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to trigger the change value of input and then simulate enter key press.

Let's say you have this in HTML file:

```
<input id="someId" type="text" />
```

And then you should write this in your JS file:

```
function simulateEnterPress(element) {
    var e = $.Event("keypress"); // Create a keypress event
    e.which = 13; // Set the pressed key to "Enter"
    element.trigger(e); // Trigger the event
}

function doAction() {
    var inputElement = $("#someId"); // Get the input element
    inputElement.val(/* someValue */); // Set value of the input
    simulateEnterPress(inputElement);
}
```

After this Enter key keypress event will be triggered and it will be processed by your `keypress` event handler.

Comment: @it changes the value, but it doesnt press enter. Oh i forgot to say, the input box is also the thing that triggers the event too, there is no extra button. Here's what i have got:var simulateEnterPress = function(element) {
    var e = $.Event("keypress"); // Create a keypress event
    e.which = 13; // Set the pressed key to "Enter"
    element.trigger(e); // Trigger the event
}

var showPage = function(){
    var inputElement = $(".Paging_Input"); // Get the input element
    inputElement.val(16); // Set value of the input
    simulateEnterPress(".Paging_Input");
}

Comment: You don't have to change the parameters for `simulateEnterPress`. In your code change `simulateEnterPress(".Paging_Input");` back to `simulateEnterPress(inputElement)`.

Comment: Check this jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/e3531arc/1/ It works, maybe you have to fix something in your code

Comment: I don't want the user to do it, i just want to do it all with jquery/javascript

Comment: nvm i think it's just this input field. it's not working at all.